# How to use a method define in configuration classes?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I created a config class in one project , defined a method,and trying import a config in another project and call the defined method,but I am getting null pointer exception.

I created bean with config class, and tried with autowire annotation but it did not work for me

```
projectA:

@Configuration
public class DepositServiceConfig
{
    @Bean
    public DepositService depositService()
    {
        return new DepositService(depositModel.user_permisisons);
    }
}

public class DepositService
{
    private final DepositModel model;

    public DepositService(depositModel model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public boolean hasRestrictions(string access)
    {
        return //
    }
}

ProjectB:
@Import({
     DepositServiceConfig.class,
    })
public class DepositApp{
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(DepositApp.class, args);
    }
}


@Component
public class ClientDeposits
{


    @Autowired DepositServiceConfig depositConfig;

    public boolean checkrestrcitions(){
     if(depositConfig.depositService().hasRestrictions(access)) -- here i am getting null pointer exception.
    }
```

how to use depositService() bean defined in the config class without null pointer exception

Comment: You have incorrectly autowired DepositServiceConfig, it's a config and should not be autowired. You need to autowire DepositService in the ClientDeposits class and use that bean. Call method on that bean.

Comment: I tried @Autowired DepositService depositService  in ClientDeposits, but still getting null exception

Answer (score 0):

Adding `@Component` to `public class DepositService` solves your problem. You must indicate DepositService as a spring component to get a managed bean.

Comment: no need to annotate @component on the DepositService class, as it's bean already being created in the config.